# Why is $|\psi_n-f|^p \leq2^p |f|^p$ when $|\psi_n|\leq |f|$?

Tags: inequality

Why is $|\psi_n-f|^p\leq 2^p |f|^p$ when $|\psi_n|\leq|f|$?

Is it true that $|a+b|^p\leq 2^p (|a|^p+|b|^p)$?

Comment: For the inequality in the title use the triangle inequality: $|\psi-f| \leq |\psi| + |f|$ in conjunction with $|\psi| \leq |f|$. btw why is this tagged measure theory?

Comment: I could only get $|\psi_n-f|^p\leq 2^{p+1} |f|^p$. This is shown up in a measure theory book to prove simple functions are dense in Lp.

Comment: Once you get $|\psi - f|\leq 2|f|$ you can just "raise the inequality to the power $p$" (or better said: use that $x^p$ is increasing for $p>0$ so $|a|\leq |b| \iff |a|^p \leq |b|^p$). The question as phrased has little to with measure theory so `inequality` is probably a better tag here.

Comment: tag updated. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality in question can be proved by the following simple estimate:

$$ |a+b| \leq |a|+|b| \leq 2\max\{|a|,|b|\}. $$

For the second inequality, notice that if $p \geq 1$, then $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex and hence

$$\left|\frac{a+b}{2}\right|^p \leq \frac{|a|^p + |b|^p}{2}$$

by Jensen's inequality. If $0 \leq p < 1$, then for any $x, y \geq 0$, there exists $\xi \in [0, y]$ such that

$$ (x+y)^p - y^p \underset{\text{MVT}}{=} x \cdot p (x + \xi)^{p-1} \leq x \cdot x^{p-1} = x^p. $$

This gives

$$|a+b|^p \leq (|a|+|b|)^p \leq |a|^p + |b|^p. $$

Combining, we have

$$ |a+b|^p \leq \max\{2^{p-1}, 1\} (|a|^p + |b|^p). $$

Comment: For the second inequality let $c=\max(|a|,|b|)$ and $d=\min (|c|,|d|) .$ Then $|a+b|^p\leq$  $(2 c)^p\leq$ $ \leq (2 c)^p +(2 d)^p=$ $2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p).$